# What does exec 3>&1 4>&2 1>>/tmp/output.log2>&1 do in a bash script?

Tags: bash

I saw something like this in a bash script

```
exec 3>&1 4>&2 1>>/tmp/output.log 2>&1
```

As far I understand, the stdout is redirected to a new fd 3 and stderr to 4.  What does 1 and 2 fd hold then and what does it mean to redirecto `1>> file` as well `2>&1`?

I see the output as well as err from the script is written to `/tmp/output.log`.

I want the script to write stdout and stderr to the `/tmp/output.log` as well as display in console while it is running.  How should the redirection look like?

Comment: https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=exec+3%3E%261+4%3E%262+1%3E%3E%2Ftmp%2Foutput.log+2%3E%261

Comment: Thanks for the hint but its not explanatory enough and does not give a clue on what I want to achieve.

Comment: We do in fact have questions with answers advising people to do exactly this already in the knowledgebase (the questions are of the form "how do I undo an `exec`?"; doing so requires making a backup copy, as the code here is making a backup on FD 1 as FD 3, and a backup of FD 2 as FD 4; allowing `>&3 2>&4` to be used later to get the original stdout and stderr back)

Comment: That said, your title asks one thing ("what is this code doing?"), and your body asks another ("how do I accomplish specific thing X?"). To avoid making your question eligible to be closed as too broad to be on-topic, you should ask only one question at a time.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy for the explanation.  I shell remember your suggestion to ask one question per post when I post something next time.

Answer (score 0):

`exec 3>&1 4>&2 1>>/tmp/output.log 2>&1` does the following:

1. make file descriptor 3 a copy of `stdout`
2. make file descriptor 4 a copy of `stderr`
3. redirect-append `stdout` to file `/tmp/output.log`
4. make `stderr` a copy of `stdout`

File descriptors 3 and 4 are maybe used here as temporary storage, such that the initial `stdout` and `stderr` can be restored with `exec 1>&3 2>&4`.

The third redirection sends `stdout` to `/tmp/output.log` in append mode. The last redirection makes `stderr` a copy of `stdout`, that is, also sends `stderr` to `/tmp/output.log` in append mode. Note that the order of these 4 redirections matters.

*I want the script to write `stdout` and `stderr` to the `/tmp/output.log` as well as display in console while it is running. How should the redirection look like?*

Redirect `stdout` to a `tee -a /tmp/output.log` command using process substitution. Then redirect `stderr` to `stdout`. Example:

```
$ cat foo
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# redirect
exec 1> >( tee -a /tmp/output.log ) 2>&1
ls -z
echo "foo"

$ ./foo
ls: invalid option -- 'z'
Try 'ls --help' for more information.
foo

$ cat /tmp/output.log 
ls: invalid option -- 'z'
Try 'ls --help' for more information.
foo
```

If at one point in your script you want to restore `stdout` and `stderr` to their original state you can use the same trick as in the example you found:

```
$ cat foo
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# redirect
exec 3>&1 4>&2 1> >( tee -a /tmp/output.log ) 2>&1
ls -z
echo "foo"
...
# restore
exec 1>&3 2>&4
...
```